# Entity Framework, LINQ : Can't use the same model more than once in the LINQ Query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

I have a View model that I'm going to use for a tree view.

```
public class TreeviewLookupModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool HasChildren { get; set; }
        public List<TreeviewLookupModel> Children { get; set; }
    }
```

I'm using the view model above in the LINQ Query below:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<TreeviewLookupModel>> GetBranchTree()
{
    var branches = db.Branches
                   .Include(_ => _.Projects)
                   .Select(branch => new TreeviewLookupModel
                   {
                       Id = branch.Brn_ID,
                       Name = branch.Brn_Name,
                       HasChildren = branch.Projects.Any(_ => _.Brn_ID == branch.Brn_ID),
                       Children = branch.Projects.Select(project => new TreeviewLookupModel
                       {
                           Id = project.ID_Project,
                           Name = project.P_Name,
                           HasChildren = project.Buildings.Any(_ => _.ID_Project == project.ID_Project),
                           Children = project.Buildings.Select(building => new TreeviewLookupModel
                           {
                               Id = building.ID_Building,
                               Name = building.B_Name
                           })
                           .ToList()
                       })
                       .ToList()
                   })
                   .ToListAsync();
    return await branches;
}
```

The Query above when I execute it , EF generates an exception saying that I can't use the same view model twice in a single linq query.

I was able to resolve this issue with the work around below:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<object>> GetBranchTree()
        {
            var branches = db.Branches
                           .Include(_ => _.Projects)
                           .Select(branch => new
                           {
                               Id = branch.Brn_ID,
                               Name = branch.Brn_Name,
                               HasChildren = branch.Projects.Any(_ => _.Brn_ID == branch.Brn_ID),
                               Children = branch.Projects.Select(project => new
                               {
                                   Id = project.ID_Project,
                                   Name = project.P_Name,
                                   HasChildren = project.Buildings.Any(_ => _.ID_Project == project.ID_Project),
                                   Children = project.Buildings.Select(building => new
                                   {
                                       Id = building.ID_Building,
                                       Name = building.B_Name
                                   })
                                   .ToList()
                               })
                               .ToList()
                           })
                           .ToListAsync();
            return await branches;
        }
```

Basically I've Removed "TreeViewLookupModel" from my query and created anonymous objects instead.

Would this approach be considered as spaghetti code or a bad practice?
If yes, is there a solution for using the same view model more than once without EF throwing exceptions?

Thanks!

Comment: Lazy Loading, Explicit or Eager, which one are you using? maybe you have a Circular Reference issue?

Comment: off topic but....HasChildren is not necessary if Children is null, just check for null instead.  it is the same as setting HasChildren to false.  This may help simplify your code and any unnecessary linq used

Comment: @Aaron.S that's the query I'm using, the first one in my question. and that's the error EF generates "ExceptionMessage": "The type 'ACS.Hub.Services.RestfulAPI.Controllers.TreeviewLookupModel' appears in two structurally incompatible initializations within a single LINQ to Entities query. A type can be initialized in two places in the same query, but only if the same properties are set in both places and those properties are set in the same order.",

Comment: You're right I'll refactor it thaaanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select entities with multiple and nested levels without using Include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40660116/select-entities-with-multiple-and-nested-levels-without-using-include)

Comment: @FCin Yes found my answer there. Thank you very much!

Comment: but is it a good practice to use anonymous types in a situation like that?

Comment: Why are you casting "ToList()"  your children ?

Comment: @CelsoLívero that's me telling EF to execute a sql statement , I've tried AsEnumerable() but it wouldn't compile